# SoapUI endpoint error randomly

Tags: soap, soapui, jax-rpc

I don't understand something about SoapUI and his mockservice's behaviour.
I'm using the client of SoapUI (testcase) and a Java EE application with JAX-RPC.

**My problem is :**

when I'm trying to call any webservice, from my Java Client, or the testcase of SoapUI, the mockservice return a well message at first call, and the error below at the second call, with the same call or not.
But if I'm waiting, It works ...

So, I have enabled the option in SOAPui : "*close HTTP connection after each SOAP request*" and it works all the time...

**So my question is :**

"**Is it a normal behaviour of the mockservice, and how to implement this with my java client ?**"

Thank you all.

```
 <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
```

Answer (score 8):

OK,
I found a solution on the forum of SoapUI : http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5648

> It is when you have the settings flag "HTTP Settings/Logs wire content of all mock requests" set to true.
>   => Uncheck the flag and it works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot !

I had the same problem, using SoapUI 5.1.2 Pro.
After receiving first asynchronous response to the MockService, the MockService
stopped and could not receive any more responses for the request I sent.
The error message was:
Thu Jul 02 12:59:44 CEST 2015:ERROR:An error occurred [Missing operation for soapAction [XXXX] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]], see error log for details

In SoapUI Settings:
File->Preferences->Http Settings: "Enable Mock HTTP log", uncheck box:
"Logs wire content of all mock requests".

Now I receive several asynchronous responses in a row, and give response back on them.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem may happen when two mock services run with the same endpoint address (including port and path) on SoapUI.

Comment: I second that - in my case I was running two different mock services generated from two different WSDLs on localhost, from the same port. One of the services behaved VERY strangely - this stopped happening once I changed the port number of the second service...